# Accessing Web APIs Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

Here's a situation where I have an web application that needs to:

- Access it's core database via a Web API layer (so I don't have direct access to its repositories/uow)
- Access other external third-party APIs for additional data/actions

What are best practices/patterns that are recommended to wrap and connect to these individual APIs?

Comment: I don't really get your question, are you looking for a kind of ws-* facade ? A Service Broker ?

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm still novice with .NET & patterns but am trying to achieve a good design. For example, say I have simple form which collects a driver's details and uses a third party REST API to retrieve car models/makes for the user to select. I don't want my controller littered with HttpClient requests, so would it make sense to create a repository or some other class for each of the web api services? Where would I place these classes in a layered project?

Answer (score 0):

Ha ok, I get it now :) It really depends on the amount of data you're consuming and the amount of request. You can have for example a local cache on the client side containing the data if they are pretty small, you can replicate them in one of your database if they don't often changes and just subscribe for updates on the remote webservice.

So yes, it can make sense if you really have a lot of requests but after you'll have to manage the consistency of the cache and the update.

For me, I would include that in the DAL and unify everything behind a facade so your client consume in the same way internal and external data.

For the cache, it depends, client cache, server cache, "SQL ws-* replication",...

But once again it really depends on the kind/amount of data and the acceptable load/requests.

Perhaps a bit more of details ?
(There's no correct answer for me, already depends on the context, the goals, the time, the budget, etc, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am author of Entity REST SDK.

Accessing Database with Web API will lead to security nightmare, as you will have to code security rules with every operation. That is quite tedious.

So we have created Entity REST SDK which lets you setup REST API quickly along with security rules as simple lambda expressions which does most of your security related logic.

Security Context works at field level as well, so if an admin requests an object, he will receive all fields but if a user requests same object from same url, he will only receive certain fields. Same applies to modification as well as foreign keys.

https://entityrestsdk.codeplex.com/

We also have JSON to LINQ converter which lets you customize your queries with JSON syntax within query string as explained.